# Is it legal to use fonts downloaded by Winetricks?

Tags: wine, fonts, legal

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it legal to install msttcorefonts package? Is Wine legal?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/134549/is-it-legal-to-install-msttcorefonts-package-is-wine-legal)

If I run `winetricks` then select the default Wine prefix then select install a font, I find some fonts.

Is it legal to use this fonts? Especially Microsoft fonts such as Tahoma?

Comment: No,this is not duplicate.your topic asking about legality of using wine to install ms app & of msttcorefonts which was a project started by Microsoft in 1996 to create a standard pack of fonts for the Internet.It was terminated in 2002 & published as freeware but updated versions of the fonts released in following years were not published as freeware. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Core_fonts_for_the_Web .BUT I ask about fonts downloaded by winetricks and this fonts contain Tahoma which is not one of corefonts also this version of it puplished after 2002.so you can see it is completely different

Comment: We are not lawyers here on AskUbuntu. The information in the link should cover as much as you need to know.  If in doubt you should discuss this with Microsoft themselves.