# How can I install fonts in Wine?

Tags: 12.04, wine, fonts, software-installation

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 and I just installed Wine.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-wine/ppa 
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get install wine1.5 
sudo apt-get install winetricks
```

The installation was not fully successful because it gave me the error that fonts were not installed.

Without the fonts I cant open any program. I have tried to copy fonts from Windows to `/usr/share/fonts` but there is no paste option.

Also I have googled and saw somewhere that you can install fonts via *winetricks*. If so, how does it work? Can I open winetricks? How can I do the install?

Regards

Comment: You should specify exactly how you are trying to install wine.  I usually already have restricted-extras installed in the beginning, but it sounds like that might be the problem.  Install from the wine edgers ppa goes fine for me.

Comment: Yes i installed from that
Thats how i did it:
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-wine/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install wine1.5
sudo apt-get install winetricks
But it gave me error it didnt install fonts :(

Comment: Install the msttcorefonts and see if it works. http://askubuntu.com/questions/134549/is-it-legal-to-install-msttcorefonts-package-is-wine-legal

Comment: ttf-mscorefonts-installer is already the newest version.

Comment: :/ try the full restricted-extras.  the install worked here

Comment: sorry i don't understand
What do u mean by try the full restricted-extras

Comment: ubuntu-restricted-extras

Comment: still doesnt work
i will try reinstalling wine again

Answer (score 6):

You can type this in the terminal:

```
sudo apt-get --reinstall install ttf-mscorefonts-installer
```

Then you need to accept license when prompted, you use TAB and ENTER to accept the license.

If the above doesn't work try one of these ways to mannually add the fonts:

You can paste Windows fonts to `/home/YOURUSERNAME/.wine/drive_c/windows/Fonts`.

Or you can paste Windows fonts to `/usr/share/fonts/`, although to enable paste option in there you need to open Nautilus as root:

```
gksu nautilus /usr/share/fonts
```

And then you will be able to paste Windows fonts there.

Comment: So in order for wine to work, where i should paste the fonts?
On wine folder or /usr/share/fonts/ ?

Comment: Try wine folder first, if it doesn't work try `/usr/share/fonts/`

Comment: Actually there wasnt any fonts folder on .wine/drive_c/windows/Fonts so i created one.Now i can open some .exe but there are some that i can't open.For example when i try to open software called web cruiser in taskbar in ubuntu is says opening webcruiser.exe and then it dissapears

Comment: So you've successfuly pasted Windows fonts there? If so font's problems may be fixed and possible not oppening webcruiser.exe is another problem? Try pasting fonts in '/usr/share/fonts/' folder too.

Comment: It still doesn't work.When i try to open webcruiser.exe it says "opening webcruiser.exe" in taskbar and it dissapears after about 3 seconds (webcruiser.exe doesn't open)
Please give me a solution

Comment: Hmm, the last thing I can think is to try reinstalling wine:
`sudo apt-get --reinstall install wine`

Comment: That didn't work again but thanks anyway for helping.