# Can Kingsoft Office be installed?

Tags: software-installation, wps-office

Can Kingsoft Office be installed in Ubuntu?

Comment: Check [here](http://appdb.winehq.org)

Comment: Look at " Guide how to change WPS Office for Linux(Kingsoft Office Chinese ver.) to English" - http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2121775

Comment: That's a job for the wine windows installer. :)

Answer (score 8):

Yes, you can. At this time Kingsoft office ([known as WPS office in China](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kingsoft_Office)) has a official beta version for Linux, you can found more information in [their official website](http://linux.wps.cn/).

After installing the debian installer, the office suite is initially in Chinese locale. To make it in English, you can

```
cd /opt/kingsoft/wps-office/office6/cfgs
sudo nano setup.cfg
```

Then change the line “UILanguage=2052” to

```
UILanguage=default
```

Comment: Is it really the same software?.

Comment: @UriHerrera Yes, it is the same software. This article on wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kingsoft_Office explained that Kingsoft office still sold as WPS Office, and at the end of the official website you can found this message: "Copyright © 2008-2012 Kingsoft Office Corporation"

Comment: Alright. Maybe add some more information about it being WPS Office to your answer.

Answer (score 6):

1. Download the latest linux Kingsoft Office package from

   http://wps-community.org/download.html
2. Run

   ```
   sudo dpkg -i kingsoft-office_9.1.0.4184~a12p1_i386.deb
   ```

   Change `kingsoft-office_9.1.0.4184~a12p1_i386.deb` for the name of the package actually downloaded.
3. Voilà

**Note #1**: If you had installed Kingsoft Office for Linux Beta1 (`wps-office_8.1.0.3724~b1p2_i386.deb`), [you must remove that one first](https://askubuntu.com/a/299227/58950).

Kingsoft Office (also called WPS Office) will keep nagging about MS Office fonts needed. The options are to ignore it and go ahead with your life, or download and install them from http://wps-community.org/download/fonts/ on your machine. Note that these fonts are not the ones you get with [`ttf-mscorefonts-installer`](https://askubuntu.com/q/134549/58950).

**Note #2**: Starting from Kingsoft Office for Linux Alpha12 Patch1 (released 2013-09-18), the program will notify the user of upgrades.

Now, [LibreOffice](http://www.libreoffice.org) is definitely superior (and it supports MS Office files), but if you are forced to work and share a lot Microsoft Office files, you might want to give it a try: for the little that I've seen, in some cases the `.docx` *et al.* files appear better (or closely to how they look in Windows; layout, tables and all) under Kingsoft Office than with LO. *Your mileage may vary*.

I haven't used it too much, nor I have to work mostly with MS Office files, and the improvements I've seen occur in a just few examples; so my verdict is that the advantages are, at this point, marginal if any. And this is a non-*libre* software.

Or maybe you just want to see for yourself the tabbed interface, which many of us [would like to have in the future in LibreOffice](https://www.libreoffice.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=64847).

I tested this in Ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: Doesn't LibreOffice support the .doc format as well?(Microsoft Office documents)

Comment: @Nick thank you for pointing out this omission. I've edited my answer and clarified a little my position.

Comment: Is this up to date?

Comment: @Seth Now it is; as of 2013-10-07 the latest package is Linux Alpha12 Patch1. I have also added a link to the font downloads page. Thanks for the heads up!

Answer (score 4):

### Pre 12.04

No.

- There is no native installer;
- [Wine shows it with a garbage or bronze rating](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?bShowAll=true&bIsQueue=false&bIsRejected=false&sClass=version&sTitle=&sReturnTo=&iId=24395). In the best situation ("bronze") it still did not work well enough that it would likely be practically usable. (See [the details](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=24395&iTestingId=69474&bShowAll=true).)

---

What can Kingsoft Office do that you can not do with LibreOffice, Apache OpenOffice Writer and/or AbiWord?

Comment: *What can Kingsoft Office do that you can not do with LibreOffice, Apache OpenOffice Writer and/or AbiWord?* It looks better.

Comment: @Seth I disagree on that. Apart from the green splash screen LO uses ;)

Comment: See the newspapers!! There is a deb installer!! :O http://askubuntu.com/a/367564/169736

Comment: cool but does it work in 11.10 @Braiam >:-D

Comment: Excuse me... http://wps-community.org/download.html

Comment: @wilf that was created after my post BUT be sure to read their restrictions: AMERICANS downloading it are violating their license and confirm they may be sued. http://www.wps.cn/privacy/unixdistribute/. "Kingsoft authorizes you the non-exclusive right to use the "Product" in the territorial scope in the world (“Authorized Territorial Scope”) except for North America (including only the United States, Canada and Greenland, similarly hereinafter)"

Comment: and my answer is still correct: the PPA does not work on 11.10 and it is intended for 12.04 and higher @wilf

Comment: @Rinzwind there, now nobody knows that OP uses 11.10 :P

Comment: Yeah, you don't know that unless you look in the edit history... Anyway, for those reading it now, they are supposed be using 12.04 or higher, as otherwise it is apparently not relevant to this forum :D. Sorry anyway.

Comment: @Rinzwind the North American clause is no longer in the privacy/distribute statement.

Answer (score 1):

This method works in Ubuntu 13.04 64-bits.

1. Go to the [Download page](http://community.wps.cn/download/), scroll down until you see wps-office_8.1.0.3724~b1p2_i386.**deb** file (the one that ends in deb). Download it.
2. Install gdebi: `sudo apt-get install gdebi`
3. In a terminal run: `sudo gdebi Downloads/wps-office_8.1.0.3724~b1p2_i386.deb`, press Y (accept).
4. Done.