# How to update Kingsoft Office?

Tags: installation, package-management

I've installed the previous beta version and would like to upgrade to the new version (as announced on [omgubuntu](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2013/05/microsoft-office-clone-wps-updates-interface-improves)). When I try doing so via the Software Center I get a message that a certain package already exists (see hereunder) and can not be overwritten. I thus wanted to de-install the previous package but the Software Center doesn't even mention Kingsoft as being installed . Now what?

```
Unpacking kingsoft-office (from .../kingsoft-office_9.1.0.4032~a10_i386.deb) ...

dpkg: error processing /home/kcosyns/Downloads/kingsoft-office_9.1.0.4032~a10_i386.deb (--install):

trying to overwrite '/usr/bin/wps', which is also in package wps-office 8.1.0.3724~b1p2

dpkg-deb (subprocess): failed in write on buffer copy for failed to write to pipe in copy: Broken pipe

dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste returned error exit status 2
```

Comment: This is a bug in the packaging, and bugs are off topic for Ask Ubuntu as per the FAQ. You need to report the bug to whomever created the packages. Also, your question seems to be missing some content, as the first line is cut short, and there isn't a clear question here.

Answer (score 2):

You would have to remove previous version first, named `wps-office`. See below on how to do it.

Then you [install with `dpkg`](https://askubuntu.com/a/310204/58950):

```
sudo dpkg -i kingsoft-office_9.1.0.4032~a10_i386.deb
```

To remove Kingsoft Office (also called WPS Office) you can run:

```
sudo apt-get remove wps-office
```

or

```
sudo apt-get remove kingsoft-office
```

If you want to completely remove, including configuration files, run:

```
sudo apt-get purge wps-office
```

or

```
sudo apt-get purge kingsoft-office
```

The package name was changed from `wps-office` (version 8.1.0) to `kingsoft-office` (version 9.1.0).

Comment: tx, I'll try that

Comment: Thanks4 suggestion, but did not work for me

Comment: @RobinLovelace, did you try removing the previous package? I did not have it installed, so I wouldn't know if that's a problem. We can [consider reopening the question](http://askubuntu.com/help/reopen-questions), whether you are successful or not.

Comment: @carnendil I did 'try' removing it, but not very hard: couldn't find the package in synaptic (searched for "kingsoft" and "office"). Thanks for letting us know the package name: that allows it to be removed via synaptic (search for "wps") or via apt-get remove as you suggested. After that has been performed your top solution works perfectly. The question should definitely be re-opened IMO: many will have installed the old version and now want the new version installed.