# how to support exe files in ubuntu and how to download wine

Tags: helpfile

please help me so that i can use all windows applications and softwares so i could daily use ubuntu.I need microsoft office 13,photoshop cs6,nero 10 and other all softwares to support in my ubuntu software please help to make the ubuntu os which is installed in my pc to support exe files.

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo apt-get install wine
```

can install wine in your Ubuntu.

To check the application you wish to install in Ubuntu through wine will be supported by wine or not you must check the application in wine database.

MS Office 2013 : http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=26323

photoshop cs6 :http://appdb.winehq.org/appview.php?appId=17

Nero http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=152

Note: Ubuntu have awesome alternatives for all the applications you have mentioned above.

Comment: After install, you may need to run `sudo nano /usr/share/applications/wine.desktop` and mark `NoDisplay=` as `false`, so it should appear in the dash and the right-click and open menu *(This only occasionally seems to be a problem.)*.

Answer (score 1):

@rajagenupula seems to have answered this question - but here are a few non-Windows alternatives:

**Microsoft Office 2010**

*Kingsoft Office 2013*

I like this. It has a nice interface than the bog standard libreoffice - **and the latest `4207` 2013 version can edit Office 2010 .docx** documents. It is sort of the Chinese version of Microsoft Office, but support for English and other languages has be simply brilliant in the latest versions.

It is available as a one-install package, which provides versions of Word, Presentation/Powerpoint, and Calc/Excel. For most uses, libreoffice works OK, but this is sometimes necessary for compatibility.

[image: Kingsoft Word]

**I will also note that any Americans who may want to use this may have a problem, due to licensing things - https://askubuntu.com/a/235960/178596**

> Be sure to read their
>   restrictions: AMERICANS downloading it are violating their license and
>   confirm they may be sued. http://wps.cn/privacy/unixdistribute
>   "Kingsoft authorizes you the non-exclusive right to use the "Product" in the
>   territorial scope in the world (“Authorized Territorial Scope”) except
>   for North America (including only the United States, Canada and
>   Greenland, similarly hereinafter)"
>   Credit to @Rinzwind

You can download the .deb from here:
http://wps-community.org/download.html

There is a guide to installing .deb files here:
http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/ubuntu-linux-how-do-i-install-deb-packages/

For both this AND libreoffice, you will get better performance if you can get the Windows fonts and install them onto your Ubuntu computer. You can copy them from the `fonts` direcotry on a Windows computer on its `C:` drive.

*Libreoffice*

This may be installed by default, and is now pretty much the default word processor for most linux distros. It works, but my problem with it is that can even have problems editing 2003 .doc files.

Available [here](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/search/?q=libreoffice&op=) and possibly in Software Centre.

Website: http://www.libreoffice.org/

---

**Photoshop**

*GNU Image Manipulation Program* - Gimp 2.8 onwards
Simply brilliant. If something is not supported, you just need to install a plugin for it. Free, and far less annoying that Photoshop.

[image: GIMP]

Available [here](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/gimp/) and possibly in Software Centre.

Website: http://www.gimp.org/

---

**Nero**

I have found this - [Nero Linux](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nero_Linux) - on Wikipedia, but I do not know where to get it from.

Finding alternatives for this are more complicated - but here are a few:

*K3B - Disc Image Writer*

[image: K3B]

Available [here](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/k3b/) and possibly in software centre.

*Kdenlive - Video editor*

Not brilliant  - but it works.

[image: Kdenlive]

Available [here](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/kdenlive/) and possibly in software centre.

Comment: Brother I did mentioned that we have alternatives . any way nice work. +1

Comment: I know that, I thought I would a few in any way - It took me a while to find Kingsoft Office, even though it apparently has funny licensing things. It is the only way I can really finish my A Levels using my laptop, as I have edit 2010 `.docx` documents... Thank you.

Comment: Libreoffice has support for docx. I have been using it on both Ubuntu and Windows to make save docx. Kingsoft on the other hand is discriminatory to say the least. But to each its own ;)

Comment: we have many more alternatives that could work better.

Comment: Yes but in libreoffice the formatting goes to *beep*...  I literally have to use, otherwise I can't do my work (libreoffice **literally** turns the pages upside down - dunno why, probably a bug.) I would much prefer using just libreoffice, especially if it had a less annoying interface, and worked properly with Windows things. Actually, it would be much better if I did not have use .docx etc full stop - but the curriculum in the UK seems very heavily Windows based...