# What default Windows Software Alternatives does Ubuntu have!

Tags: windows, software-recommendation, migration

This former Windows user is all set with a new Ubuntu installed to his box. And now I'd like to know what default applications I have in my system? And esp. for these categories:

- Audio
- Video
- Graphics & Design
- Internet & Network
- Torrent client
- Office Packages (Word Processors, Spreadsheet, etc.)
- System and Administrative tools
- command line emulator

Comment: Question that generate lists are not suited for Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Yes, this question will be most likely closed. And there are other sites which deal exactly with this stuff http://www.linuxalt.com/ http://linuxappfinder.com/alternatives http://alternativeto.net/

Comment: Still, not a bad thing, is it? @Braiam

Comment: @falconer, sure there are... and in this website too there are queries for such recommendation... this was just an attempt to document some general applications...

Comment: That's nice that you want to help new users, but big list questions are not allowed here (AFAIK). See the notice [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/30334/what-application-indicators-are-available). A *Where to find alternative programs?* with an answer containing links to these dedicated sites wouldn't go against the rules. I guess.

Comment: @falconer, that sure looks a better title... I'll set it to something like that... thank you the suggest and the links...

Comment: @ajThapa as your question is right now, then it's a duplicated

Comment: @Braiam, seems it's bound to close anyways (if not one of the "not baad!" dupes)... well, used my reopen vote, which I think is all I could do... rest to the moderators....

Comment: @Seth, Takkat, Braiam, Avinash Raj, Eric Carvalho: I've edited the question... Please do comment whether or not it's better than before. Thanks.

Comment: @hash AWESOME QUESTION AND ANSWER!! -can't help it commenting-!! I've even bookmarked the question!!!!

Comment: @wilf http://meta.askubuntu.com/a/7947/169736

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A little about [**Ubuntu**](http://www.ubuntu.com/)...

[Ubuntu](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_%28operating_system%29) is a *Debian*-based *Linux* operating system, with [Unity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unity_%28user_interface%29) as its default desktop environment. It is based on *free* software and named after the Southern African philosophy of *ubuntu* (literally, *"human-ness"*), which often is translated as *"humanity towards others"* or *"the belief in a universal bond of sharing that connects all humanity"*.

Development of Ubuntu is led by *Canonical Ltd.*, owned by South African entrepreneur [Mark Shuttleworth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mark_Shuttleworth). According to Canonical, the Ubuntu project is committed to the principles of open source development; people are encouraged to use *[free software](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software), study how it works, improve upon it, and distribute it*.

Homepage: [ubuntu.com](http://ubuntu.com/)

---

#### Recommended links for intro. about application search and installation process in Ubuntu:

- [How do I enable the “Universe” and other repositories?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/148638/how-do-i-enable-the-universe-repository)
- [How to install applications in Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/307280/how-to-install-applications-in-ubuntu)

---

### Here's the list of some default applications (along with some alternatives):

(The applications that are default or have been default in the past are marked with an *asterisk* (*).)

**GUI Program installers**

These are some great graphical front ends for package management. Categorized applications list with description, screenshots, ratings, etc. is really helpful to search and install the application that meets your need.

- [Ubuntu Software Centre](https://launchpad.net/software-center)*
  [image: softwareCentreSnap]
- [Synaptic](http://www.nongnu.org/synaptic/)*
  [image: synapticPackageManagerSnap]
- [Kyum](http://sourceforge.net/projects/kyum/)

### Audio

---

**Audio Player** [Alt. to *Winamp*; *Windows Media Player*]

- [Audacious](http://audacious-media-player.org/)
- [amaroK](http://amarok.kde.org/)
- [Banshee](http://www.banshee-project.org/Main_Page)*
- [Rhythmbox](http://www.gnome.org/projects/rhythmbox/)*
- [VLC](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/)

**Audio Editor** [Alt. to SoundForge; Adobe Audition]

- [Audacity](http://audacity.sourceforge.net/)
- [LMMS](http://lmms.sourceforge.net/)
- [Ardour](http://ardour.org/)

**Stream Browser**

- [last.fm](http://www.last.fm/)

**CD Ripper**

- [Arson](http://arson.sourceforge.net/)
- [Sound Juicer](http://burtonini.com/blog/computers/sound-juicer)

### Video

---

**Video Player** [Alt. to BSplayer; Windows Media Player; VLC]

- [KPlayer](http://kplayer.sourceforge.net/)
- [VLC](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/)
- [Totem](http://www.gnome.org/projects/totem/)*

**Video Editor** [Alt. to Adobe Premiere]

- [LiVES](http://lives.sourceforge.net/)
- [Avidemux](http://fixounet.free.fr/avidemux/)
- [OpenShot Video Editor](http://www.openshotvideo.com)
- [Kdenlive](http://www.kdenlive.org/)

**DVD Ripper**

- [Handbrake](http://handbrake.m0k.org/)
- [Brasero](http://www.gnome.org/projects/brasero/)*

**Screen Capture**

- [Xvidcap](http://xvidcap.sourceforge.net/)
- [recordMyDesktop](http://recordmydesktop.sourceforge.net/)

### Video/Audio format converter/transcoder

---

[Alt. to FormatFactory, Total Video Converter, etc.]

- [WinFF](http://www.winff.org/)
- [HandBrake](http://handbrake.fr/)
- [Avidemux](http://avidemux.org)
- [Transmageddon](http://www.linuxrising.org/)

### Graphics & Design

---

**Image editor** [Alt. to Adobe Photoshop]

- [GIMP](http://gimp.org/)*
- [Krita](http://krita.org/)
- [Tux Paint](http://www.tuxpaint.org/)

**Image Organizer** [Alt. to Picasa]

- [Shotwell](http://yorba.org/shotwell/)*
- [F-Spot](http://f-spot.org/)
- [digiKam](http://www.digikam.org)

**Vectorgraphics editor** [Alt. to CorelDraw]

- [Inkscape](http://inkscape.org/)
- [Karbon](http://www.calligra-suite.org/karbon/)

**3D Modeler** [Alt. to 3D Max; Maya]

- [Blender3D](http://www.blender.org)
- [Wings 3D](http://www.wings3d.com/)
- [Equinox-3D](http://www.equinox3d.com/)

**Computer Aided Design** [Alt. to AutoCAD; MathCAD]

- [BRL-CAD](http://brlcad.org/)
- [FreeCAD](http://www.ar-cad.com/)

### Internet & Network

---

**Internet Browser** [Alt. to Internet Explorer]

- [Chromium](http://www.chromium.org/Home)
- [Firefox](http://www.mozilla.com/firefox/)*
- [Opera](http://www.opera.com/)
- [SeaMonkey](http://www.mozilla.org/projects/seamonkey/)
- [Konqueror](http://www.konqueror.org/)
- [Links2](http://links.twibright.com/)
- [Lynx](http://lynx.browser.org/) - Text browser for the World Wide Web

**E-mail** [Alt. to Outlook Express, Outlook]

- [Evolution](http://www.gnome.org/projects/evolution/)*
- [Thunderbird](http://www.mozilla.com/thunderbird/)*
- [KMail](http://kmail.kde.org/)

**Usenet/Newsreader** [Alt. to Outlook Express, Forte Agent]

- [Pan](http://pan.rebelbase.com/)

**RSS Feed Reader**

- [Liferea](http://liferea.sourceforge.net/)

**FTP Client** [Alt. to FileZilla; WS_FTP]

- [gFTP](http://gftp.seul.org/)
- [FileZilla](http://filezilla-project.org/)

**Instant messenger** [Alt. to AIM; ICQ; MSN; Yahoo!; Jabber; Gadu-gadu]

- [Pidgin](http://pidgin.im/) (Formerly GAIM)
- [Kopete](http://kopete.kde.org/)
- [aMSN](http://www.amsn-project.net/)
- [Kadu](http://www.kadu.im)

**Internet Relay Chat** [Alt. to mIRC]

- [XChat](http://xchat.org/)
- [Konversation](http://konversation.kde.org/)

**Torrents**

- [Deluge](http://deluge-torrent.org/)
- [BitTornado](http://www.bittornado.com/)
- [aria2](http://aria2.sourceforge.net/)
- [Transmission](http://www.transmissionbt.com/)*
- [KTorrent](http://ktorrent.org/)
- [qBittorrent](http://qbittorrent.sourceforge.net/)
- [vuze](http://www.vuze.com/)

**Download Manager/Accelerator**

- [uGet](http://ugetdm.com/)
- [Axel](http://axel.alioth.debian.org)
- [Steadyflow](https://launchpad.net/steadyflow)

**VoIP** [Alt. to Skype]

- [Skype](http://www.skype.com/)
- [Ekiga](http://www.ekiga.org/)

### Graphical User Interface

---

**Desktop Environment** [Alt. to Explorer, Aston, GeoShell]

- [Unity](https://unity.ubuntu.com/)
- [KDE](http://www.kde.org/)
- [Gnome](http://www.gnome.org/)
- [Xfce](http://www.xfce.org/)
- [Cinnamon](http://cinnamon.linuxmint.com/)
- [Trinity](http://www.trinitydesktop.org/)
- [Mate](http://mate-desktop.org/)
  *(This AU page lists some more with great snapshots. Must visist: [What different desktop environments and shells are available?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65083/what-different-desktop-environments-and-shells-are-available))*

### Development

---

**Web** [Alt. to Dreamweaver]

- [Aptana](http://www.aptana.com/)
- [Bluefish](http://bluefish.openoffice.nl/)
- [CSSed](http://cssed.sourceforge.net/) - CSS Editor
- [KompoZer](http://www.kompozer.net/)
- [Screem](http://www.screem.org/)

**IDE** [Alt. to MS Visual studio]

- [KDevelop](http://www.kdevelop.org/)
- [NetBeans](https://netbeans.org/)
- [Anjuta](http://anjuta.sourceforge.net/) - Anjuta is a versatile IDE for C and C++, written for GTK/GNOME
- [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/) - An extensible frameworks, tools and runtimes for building, deploying and managing software across the lifecycle
- [Eric](http://eric-ide.python-projects.org/index.html) - Python IDE
- [Qt](http://qt-project.org/)
- [Geany](http://geany.uvena.de/)

### Office

---

**Office Suite** [Alt. to MS Office, Adobe Reader, etc.]

- [LibreOffice](http://www.libreoffice.org/)*
- [OpenOffice](http://www.openoffice.org)*
- [KingSoft Office](http://wps-community.org/download.html)
- [Scribus](http://www.scribus.net/canvas/Scribus)
- [PDFedit](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pdfedit/)
- [evince](https://projects.gnome.org/evince/)* - Document viewer for multiple document formats like PDF, Postscript, djvu, tiff, dvi, XPS, etc.

**Calendar** [Alt. to Ms Outlook]

- [Evolution](https://projects.gnome.org/evolution/)*
- [Mozilla Sunbird](http://www.mozilla.org/projects/calendar/sunbird/)

**Text Editors GUI** [Alt. to Notepad]

- [gedit](http://www.gedit.org)*
- [Leafpad](http://tarot.freeshell.org/leafpad/)
- [SciTE](http://scintilla.org/SciTE.html)

### System tools

---

**File managers**

[Alt. to Total Commander]

- [Krusader](http://www.krusader.org/)

[Alt. to Windows Explorer]

- [Konqueror](http://www.konqueror.org/)
- [Nautilus](https://wiki.gnome.org/action/show/Apps/Nautilus)*

**CD Burners** [Alt. to Nero]

- [Brasero](http://www.gnome.org/projects/brasero) *
- [K3B](http://www.k3b.org/)

**Partition Managers** [Alt. to Partition Magic]

- [Gparted](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/)*
- [QtParted](http://qtparted.sourceforge.net/)

### X Terminal Emulator

---

- gnome-terminal*
- [xterm](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/xterm.html)
- [konsole](http://konsole.kde.org/)
- [guake](https://github.com/Guake/guake)
- [yakuake](http://extragear.kde.org/apps/yakuake/)

### Other Utilities

---

**Dictionary**

- [Artha](http://artha.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/Download)
- Dictionary (gnome-dictionary)*

**Cleaning temporary/unwanted/duplicate files** [Alt. to CCleaner, etc.]

- [FSlint](http://www.pixelbeat.org/fslint/)
- [BleachBit](http://bleachbit.sourceforge.net/download/linux)
- [GtkOrphan](http://www.marzocca.net/linux/gtkorphan.html)
- [fdupes](http://code.google.com/p/fdupes/)

**System Monitor (gnome-system-monitor)*** [Alt. to Task Manager]

**Disk Utility (gnome-disk-utility)***

**Disk Usage Analyzer (baobab)***

**Archive Manager (file-roller)*** [Alt. to WinRAR, 7zip, etc.]

---

Source of the list: [ubuntuguide.org](http://ubuntuguide.org/wiki/Alternatives)

Also visit: [Ubuntu's Application Guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Applications)

---

More links for suggestions on Windows/MacOS X app alternatives:

- http://www.linuxalt.com/
- http://linuxappfinder.com/alternatives
- http://alternativeto.net/

(**Courtesy**: falconer, wilf, Jason R, Steelsouls, Kunal Sangwan, number5 for suggestions with *applications* and *links*.)

Comment: Answering your own question? May I mention you have missed some of the nastier alternatives - I have to use [Kingsoft Office](http://askubuntu.com/questions/384587/how-to-support-exe-files-in-ubuntu-and-how-to-download-wine/384632#384632) for my work in the UK *(mainly for .docx and .pptx though.)*, as it all seems to be Windows based here...

Comment: thought it would be helpful to new users... I'll update the list with _Kingsoft Office's_ link, thanks... and yup, [self answering](http://askubuntu.com/help/self-answer) for good...

Comment: [Kdenlive](http://www.kdenlive.org/) is another video editor that might be worth listing.

Comment: Kdenlive is pretty much the **only** video editor - worthwhile one anyway ;-). I would not suggest Tux Paint as alternative to photoshop, [Google Chrome](https://www.google.com/intl/en/chrome/browser/#eula) is another closed source [nasty alternative](http://askubuntu.com/a/6257/178596) for browsing, [Karbon](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/karbon/), for Vector graphics, and [Nemo](http://www.webupd8.org/2013/10/install-nemo-with-unity-patches-and.html) file manager *(Nicer than Nautilus)*. This list should be really useful to new users... +1, by the way :-)

Comment: Thanks for the list! Pleaes add Guake terminal emulator. My favorite I install it on every Ubuntu machine I have.

Answer (score 4):

I think this here is the best choice and best answer. http://linuxappfinder.com/alternatives ! Hope it helps. It has 17 page documentation.

Answer (score 2):

http://alternativeto.net/  this website have list many popular Windows apps and their Linux/Mac alternatives.