# Can Filemaker Pro work on Ubuntu?

Tags: dual-boot, wine

FileMaker Pro 12 (or any other version) work on Ubuntu?

Or will I have to run a dual boot system in order to run these Windows programs?

Comment: This site works better if your questions are formulated so that you get one answer per question, I have edited your question to reflect that and removed unwanted comments about other operative systems.

Comment: For Linux alternatives for your Windows apps, see: http://askubuntu.com/questions/389228/what-default-windows-software-alternatives-does-ubuntu-have

Answer (score 1):

FileMaker will run under [Wine](http://www.winehq.org/).  See the [Wine App Database](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=337) for complete detail.

There are other option that you can use in place of FileMaker Pro.  Some of your options are: [LibreOffice](http://www.libreoffice.org/features/base/) or [OpenOffice](https://www.openoffice.org/product/base.html) Base, [Kexi](http://www.kexi-project.org/), [Glom](http://www.glom.org/wiki/index.php?title=Main_Page), and [camelot](http://www.python-camelot.com/get-it.html).

Answer (score 0):

If you install/have Wine it might work, but if it does not work you would need a Windows system/dualboot or find something to use instead.