# WINDOWS 7 PROGRAMS USING UBUNTU

Tags: windows-7

I no longer have Windows 7 installed on the system unfortunately. Can I still use Windows 7 programs, whether or not the programs are on USB, CD or downloaded files?

Sometimes Ubuntu or the system won't read the CD/DVD drive.  What version of Bitlord and Photoshop should I download?  How do I find out what version of Ubuntu I have?

Am I searching online for Ubuntu programs under "Ubuntu" or "Linux"?

Whenever I download a program in the "Downloads" and try to install it, I get an error message that reads

> An error occurred while loading the archive

in Archive Manager. It also reads:

> End-of-central-directory signature not found. Either this file is not a zipfile, or it constitutes one disk of a multi-part archive......

Comment: please visit: [What default Windows Software Alternatives does Ubuntu have!](http://askubuntu.com/questions/389228/what-default-windows-software-alternatives-does-ubuntu-have/389230#389230) to check if there's something that interests you..

Comment: Some programs will install with WINE or Crossover Office, some won't. If an app will not install with WINE or Crossover Office, then the link in the comment above will help you find a replacement for it.

Comment: What Ubuntu-Version you have? You can check it out on system monitor. And Yes, you can use windows-programs but it depends - some are ok with wine others need a virtual pc like vmware or virtualbox others run better natively on hardware so you have to configure a dual boot.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this helps but you can use a program called wine that lets you run windows apps on ubuntu. An alternative program to photoshop is called GIMP.

Hope his helps :)