# winetricks sha1sum mismatch rename and try again

Tags: wine, winetricks

I just started using Ubuntu, and I'm trying to get Wine up and running. By using Winetricks I'm trying to install some software and I keep getting this error message:
it says

```
sha1sum mismatch! Rename /home/.cache/winetricks/win2ksp4/W2KSP4_EN.EXE and try again.
```

I don't know what it wants me to rename. I'm confused by this error screen.
Does anyone have a fix for this?

Thanks!

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu and winetricks are you using? A first step would be a newer version of winetricks...

Comment: version of Ubuntu is 14.04 and  wine version is 1.6.2

Answer (score 38):

The most conservative approach to this issue is to do exactly as the error command suggests and *rename* the file with this single command:

```
mv -v /home/.cache/winetricks/win2ksp4/W2KSP4_EN.EXE \
      /home/.cache/winetricks/win2ksp4/W2KSP4_EN.EXE_bak
```

And this might be enough. However if the issue recurs you can try an *updated* copy of `winetricks`:

```
sudo apt-get remove winetricks
wget  https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Winetricks/winetricks/master/src/winetricks
chmod +x winetricks 
sudo mv -v winetricks /usr/local/bin
```

And then you will have access to the newest version of `winetricks` which should *not* contain the 'shasum mismatch' error. The latest version that I have tested (after downloading and installing in this manner) is shown as follows:

```
andrew@ilium~$ winetricks --version
20191224-next - sha256sum: d8ac5e46ad4351faf3a3c6879044d059488001f3dd9364a5651c9e041cb97326
andrew@ilium~$
```

If this does *not* work out for you for whatever reason, and you wish to return to the Repository version of `winetricks` use the following commands in a Terminal screen:

```
sudo rm /usr/local/bin/winetricks
sudo apt-get install winetricks
```

And your system will then have returned to default: the Repository version of `winetricks`...

**References:**

- [WineHQ Wiki: Winetricks](https://wiki.winehq.org/Winetricks)

Comment: Worked for me : using the second snippet approch (with wget)

Comment: With recent versions of winetricks you need: `sudo mv -v winetricks /usr/bin` not `sudo mv -v winetricks /usr/local/bin`
`

Comment: Not sure why, but didn't work for me on Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: Second solution truly worked for me on Ubuntu 18.04 while I tried installing .NET 4.6.2. Thank You!

Comment: @kcpr Great news :)

Comment: Second solution also worked for me (first did not). Thanks!

Answer (score 19):

Update winetricks to the latest version by running

```
sudo winetricks --self-update
```

Comment: unknown option --self-update

Comment: This worked for me on Zorin OS.

Answer (score 6):

To install the latest service pack with [winehttp](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa382925(v=vs.85).aspx), try upgrading your winetricks or try under the latest development version, e.g.

```
curl -o winetricks https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Winetricks/winetricks/master/src/winetricks
sh winetricks winhttp
```

or one of the following one-liners:

```
curl -s https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Winetricks/winetricks/master/src/winetricks | sh -s winhttp
```

or:

```
sh -s winhttp < <(wget -qO- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Winetricks/winetricks/master/src/winetricks)
```

Answer (score 4):

One alternative is to modify /usr/bin/winetricks, which is a shell script, to include the updated sha256sum. You should do this **only** if you are sure that the file in your cache has been properly downloaded.

In my case, the error is:

```
sha256sum mismatch! Rename /home/coderazzi/.cache/winetricks/PowerPointViewer/PowerPointViewer.exe and try again.
```

I can check the sha256 sum of this file:

```
sha256sum /home/coderazzi/.cache/winetricks/PowerPointViewer/PowerPointViewer.exe
```

And the result is: e17cb384eeac4caf08a4f5d4bceb9697fff83fa942d2a3d9ad0294a9b1774390

Doing now:

```
grep PowerPointViewer.exe /usr/bin/winetricks
```

Shows a few lines with content:

```
...     /PowerPointViewer.exe" 249473568eba7a1e4f95498acba594e0f42e6581add4dead70c1dfb908a09423
```

It can be updated now by replacing the original sum with the new one, just by doing:

```
sudo sed -i -e s/249473568eba7a1e4f95498acba594e0f42e6581add4dead70c1dfb908a09423/e17cb384eeac4caf08a4f5d4bceb9697fff83fa942d2a3d9ad0294a9b1774390/g /usr/bin/winetricks
```

Executing now winetricks would avoid the original error.