# NOLF2 installation in 16.04

Tags: 16.04, wine, winetricks

I am trying to install NOLF2 on my ubuntu 16.04 64bit machine using Wine.
It always caused an error that made the screen freeze. 
I found a video on [youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tE0NP5eI5XI).

I installed winetricks and successfully managed to install the necessary software mentioned in the video. The list is as follows:

- allcodecs
- crypt32
- d3dx9
- directplay
- directx9
- mfc40
- mfc42
- vcrun2005
- msvcirt

While the game does start now, the audio is missing and often, the display is erratic. What can I do to make the game run?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Install `sudo apt-get install libasound2-plugins:i386` first and
   foremost. This fixes the sound
2. Shift to win32 by using `export WINEARCH=win32`. Some of the dlls can only be installed in 32bit.
3. Then uninstall the winetricks you have installed from the package manager and use the latest version from github as posted [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/750333/523471). This also prevents some problems
4. Despite all of this indeo codec installation will throw up a registry error. Ignore it
5. Now the pre-game menu will run and the sound will work. However, the problem still exists with the resolution. The game runs cropped and the mouse can not go out of the game window. Therefore, I decided to run the game in windowed mode `wine explorer /desktop=800x600 program_name`. While this is not a perfect solution, it is good enough for me.