# Installing Winetricks on Ubuntu LTS 18.04 for Steam

Tags: wine, 18.04, steam, lts, winetricks

I am a new Linux user and I am trying to get Wine to work nicely with Steam. I think I need to use winetricks to make them compatible but I can't figure out what this error wants me to do. What should I rename SteamSetup.exe to or, if that won't fix it, how can I get winetricks running?

Here is the error message.

```
sha256sum mismatch! 
Rename /home/userName/.cache/winetricks/steam/SteamSetup.exe and try again.
```

I am running the 64-bit version of Ubuntu LTS 18.04.

Comment: This might help out: https://askubuntu.com/q/749549/57576

Comment: But that's a different error..

Comment: But same idea :). Try: `mv -v /home/userName/.cache/winetricks/steam/SteamSetup.exe /home/userName/.cache/winetricks/steam/SteamSetup.exe_bak` and try again (as the message suggests). If this does not work try the newer winetricks as suggested in the other thread,,,