# Winetricks sha256sum mismatch! Rename "x" and try again

Tags: wine, steam, wget, winetricks, sha256

this is my first post so sorry for any tardiness.

I am trying to install this: [Tree of Savior - Steam](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=33550)

Which requires Winetricks in the list of dependencies.

However when downloading the Steam installer .exe I am always getting this error:

```
> user1@unknown:/tmp$ ./winetricks steam -v
> ------------------------------------------------------
You are using a 64-bit WINEPREFIX. Note that many verbs only install 32-bit versions
> of packages. If you encounter problems, please retest in a clean
> 32-bit WINEPREFIX before reporting a bug.
> ------------------------------------------------------
Using winetricks 20180513-next - sha256sum:
> e4b2f5e8703247ea422b9094293a754339fd63c890a82b777fb9dbb6b6b369b0 with
> wine-3.9 and WINEARCH=win64 Executing w_do_call steam Executing
> load_steam  Executing cd /home/user1/.cache/winetricks/steam
> Downloading
> http://media.steampowered.com/client/installer/SteamSetup.exe to
> /home/user1/.cache/winetricks/steam
> --2018-05-30 14:59:00--  http://media.steampowered.com/client/installer/SteamSetup.exe
> Resolving media.steampowered.com (media.steampowered.com)...
> 193.229.109.27, 193.229.109.25 Connecting to media.steampowered.com (media.steampowered.com)|193.229.109.27|:80... connected. HTTP request
> sent, awaiting response... 200 OK Length: 1573568 (1,5M)
> [application/octet-stream] Saving to: ‘SteamSetup.exe’
> 
> SteamSetup.exe      100%[===================>]   1,50M  1,42MB/s    in
> 1,1s    
> 
> 2018-05-30 14:59:01 (1,42 MB/s) - ‘SteamSetup.exe’ saved
> [1573568/1573568]
> 
> Executing cd /tmp
> ------------------------------------------------------
sha256sum mismatch! Rename /home/user1/.cache/winetricks/steam/SteamSetup.exe
> and try again.
> ------------------------------------------------------
```

I have tried the solutions here: [winetricks sha1sum mismatch rename and try again](https://askubuntu.com/questions/749549/winetricks-sha1sum-mismatch-rename-and-try-again)

Here: [Installing Winetricks on Ubuntu LTS 18.04 for Steam](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1041418/installing-winetricks-on-ubuntu-lts-18-04-for-steam)

Here: https://forum.winehq.org/viewtopic.php?p=47908

and in many other places. I have also tried re-downloading, re-naming et cetera. I cannot seem to find a way to successfully download and install this file.

Does anyone have any other ideas?