# Plugins/Extension to Download videos (Similar to IDM)

Tags: plugins, download-manager

How can I download videos on youtube and other platforms. Which is the best downloader compared to IDM in windows. How do I configure it and its extension in any browser on linux for example chromium?

Comment: [Can someone recommend a download manager?](http://askubuntu.com/q/32850)

Comment: Yes you can recommend

Comment: [Download YouTube videos using terminal commands ... - GeekLK](http://www.geeklk.com/2011/03/download-youtube-videos-using-terminal-commands-linuxubuntu/) - This may interest you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this for downloading videos from youtube:
[Click here (Mozilla-Addon)](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/video-downloadhelper/)

---

For download manager for command line, try: Aria2

**To install:**
`sudo apt-get install aria2`

**To run try this for options:**
    aria2c -h

**I usually just download things to the desktop then move/view/edit them from there.
In which case running aria2 with:**
`aria2c -d /home/yourusername/Desktop url/file_to_download`

It is pretty damn fast!

Comment: I am glad you like it. Try aria2 as well, it is really fast and simple.

Answer (score 1):

I have never used any 3rd party programmes, browser plugins, or web services to download videos from youtube or other platforms.

Neither am I familiar with the available tools on Windows.

Finally, questions regarding "the best of..." typically result in strongly opinion-based answers of questionable value.

The good news is: [youtube-dl](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man1/youtube-dl.1.html) is a working command-line tool in your repository. Please try it and decide for yourself whether it suites your needs.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a good downloader for windows then you can look into Free download manager, it's free of cost and has video download capabilities. Here is the link http://www.freedownloadmanager.org/

But if you want a good download manager for linux operating systems like Ubuntu then you can try "[youtube-dl](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/raring/man1/youtube-dl.1.html)". If you want to install it

open terminal/command-line and type

> sudo apt-get install youtube-dl

and press enter. After installing it type

> man youtube-dl

in terminal to get documentation on how to use it.

It's a command-line tool, you can download single video or do a batch download and the best part of it is you can download a entire playlist from youtube if you want to. It has download support for other popular sites like Dailymotion, Facebook, Metacafe, Soundcloud.

Answer (score 0):

#### For Video Downloads:

- Flash Video Downloader (a FireFox addon):

["click this link to visit and install"](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/flash-video-downloader/)

#### For video, and others:

- Download them all (for IDM like features):

[image: snap1]

["click this link to visit and install"](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/downthemall/)

---

For alternatives visit:

[What default Windows Software Alternatives does Ubuntu have!](https://askubuntu.com/questions/389228/what-default-windows-software-alternatives-does-ubuntu-have/389230#389230)

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend you [Xtreme Download Manager](http://sourceforge.net/projects/xdman/). it's identical to IDM and you can integrate it with every browser, from Browser Integration in tools menu.

Answer (score 0):

you can download a Mozilla Firefox plugin called "DownloadHelper". In Firefox toolbar, goto Tools -> Add-ons and search for "DownloadHelper". It's a superb plugin that can download even HD videos from almost any website including You-Tube.