# Download Problem using chrome

Tags: desktop-apps

How can I download videos and other files form different web sites of the internet using google chrome and fire fox?

Comment: You need to provide a lot more context otherwise this is so vague that is unanswerable.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Plugins/Extension to Download videos (Similar to IDM)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/409938/plugins-extension-to-download-videos-similar-to-idm)

Answer (score 1):

The universal answer is not to use firefox or chrome, but youtube-dl. Simply install it by running `sudo apt-get install youtube-dl` in a terminal.

A video, from [a supported site](https://rg3.github.io/youtube-dl/supportedsites.html), can be downloaded by running `youtube-dl 'http://example.com/'`, i.e. `youtube-dl 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ'` to download the video of Rick Astley's infamous hit.

You will probably find chrome extensions for some of this, but I've not seen a tool as complete as youtube-dl. It supports every major site out there.