# Questions regarding usage of software/apps

Tags: 14.04

I am presently a Windows user planning to switch to Ubuntu. My only concern is whether I will be able to use applications like Bit Torrent and Adobe products like Photoshop, Indesign and Premiere

Comment: Either use a compatibility layer such as described in @karel s link, or use an alternative program. There are several BitTorrent clients for Linux. Alternatives for the Adobe programs would be Gimp, Scribus and OpenShot, respectively, but there are others. See http://alternativeto.net/ for an overview. All these programs are free.

Comment: also have a look here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/389228/what-default-windows-software-alternatives-does-ubuntu-have